# "Correlation functions" of the connection in gravity

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, correlation-functions, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I am thinking of Einstein-Cartan gravity where the connection and the metric are considered independent objects and the connection becomes the Levi-Civita connection as a result of the equation of motion. First of all, are correlation functions defined in a theory of gravity i.e. on a curved manifold or geometry. If so how? If correlation functions on curved geometries exist, can we define correlations of the connection in the context of Einstien-Cartan gravity?